# Regex to match between words, if the closing word is absent

Tags: regex

I want to match specific parts (bold) in the following strings:

- \doc **doc1,doc2**
- \doc **doc1,doc2** \in filed1,field2
- \doc
  **doc1,doc2** \in filed1,field2 \doc **doc3,doc4** \in field3,field4

I came out with this regex `/\\doc(.*?)\\in/g`
https://regex101.com/r/dV7mF4/1

But it doesn't match the first string **doc1,doc2**. What do I need to add to my regex to match all these strings above?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: [It does not match the first string](https://regex101.com/r/nL3hW6/1).

Comment: It doesn't match, you can see it here https://regex101.com/r/dV7mF4/1

Comment: How about :  \\doc\s?(.*?)(?:\\in|\n)   https://regex101.com/r/dV7mF4/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an alternation in the positive lookahead to set the context:

```
\\doc(.*?)(?=$|\\in)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY0iB0/1)

The `(?=$|\\in)` will allow `.*?` to match up to the end of string (the `$` branch) or up to the first `\in` (the second branch).

As an alternative, you may just specify you want to match anything but `\in` after `\doc`:

```
\\doc([^\\]*(?:\\(?!in)[^\\]*)*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB3jG9/1)

Here, `[^\\]*(?:\\(?!in)[^\\]*)*` matches zero or more characters other than `\`, then 0+ sequences of `\` not followed with `in` and followed with 0+ characters other than `\`. Basically, any text that is not `\in`.

Comment: Note that the second regex can be much faster (depends on the contents) than the first one since it complies with the [unroll-the-loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) principle.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex expression to : `/\\doc(.*?)(?:\\in|\s)/g`

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/fT4pL0/1)